# Can you use Inertiajs with React Native?

Tags: react-native, inertiajs

I'm just about to start developing my first iOS app with React Native and wasn't sure if Inertiajs would be suitable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you have a response to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering about this for a while, but it turns out that you can't really use Inertia.js to build iOS apps with React Native.

In fact, Inertia.js is like a special tool designed to create SPAs based on server-side frameworks like Laravel and Symfony. It is therefore more of a web development companion than a tool that can be used for mobile applications with React Native.